# Could not load assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, json.net

The whole exception message below:

> Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile?

I have changed my PCL library to .Net standard 1.6 and i can run library and IOS project successfully. But my android project gave me the above error. If i add the Newtonsoft.Json package to it it gives me different error.

> error: package com.squareup.okhttp does not exist
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Callback

I am stuck with these errors.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens at compile-time when you have the [Newtonsoft.Json NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) installed in the .NET Standard project and do **not** have it installed in the Android project.

To fix it, add the same version of the [Newtonsoft.Json NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to the Android project as well as the .NET Standard project.